# get the price when you close order form strategy

Tags: pine-script, strategy-pattern

//hello guys,

//I would like to get the price when strategy.close  is been done

//for example:

//the close buy order is like this
strategy.close("buy", when=close>close[2])

//and I would like to create an new strategy.buy order if the new close price is high than the  //"strategy.close("buy", when=close>close[2])"
//however, I try to use valusewhen(strategy.close("buy", when=close>close[2])) is not work at all
// plz help, thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

//You can simply get the close and save it when the condition happens.

```
var float closeValue = na
exitCondition = close > close[2]

if exitCondition
    closeValue := close
```

If you wanted you could only do so when there is a trade open.
`exitCondition = close > close[2] and strategy.opentrades > 0`

Comment: thanks bro, sorry I don't know why my response is gone until now. it works, thanks again